# datatables with rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, github, datatables

I have included this  in my rails:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
```

but when I start the server I'm getting this error :

```
←[31mYou passed :github as an option for gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', but it is invalid.←[0m
```

I guess its because I'm running it locally.BTW,what will be my path if I'm running it locally?

1 more thing I followed this cast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast

I have also tried simply this:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
```

But after bundle install the css and js files are not downloaded and it is giving me file not found error.

Comment: What is your Bundler version? (run `bundle list` in terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the cast:

> The github option is new in Bundler 1.1. If you don’t have this you’ll
>   need to pass in the full git path instead.

So try to use

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'
```

Comment: lol.. I tried this one too but it didn't work may be the issue was that I was using  githhub and not git. Btw thanks for your reply it works now ..but my table is hidden any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say why your table is hidden without the view and associated javascript code.

Check if you call the `dataTable()` function on the correct table DOM element.
Also check for any fancy parameters in the call.

If that checks out, post the code for more help.

Comment: Its working now ...i was using wrong parameters for dataTable().