# jquery Data tables is throwing file not found error on require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

In order to get data tables working we need to require `dataTables/src/demo_table_jui`  in Application.css. Now I have a custom application_day.css.
Now, whenever application_day.css is loaded its throwing this error on production and dev server:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'dataTables/src/demo_table_jui'
  (in /home/app/assets/stylesheets/application_day.css:20)):
```

one more thing, I'm using this gem in group :assets for Data Tables:

```
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

These are the files included in application_day.css:-

```
 *= require_self
 *= require style.css
 *= require stylesheet_day.css
 *= require table.css
 *= require table_style.css
 *= require table_jq.css
 *= require form.css
 *= require form1.css
 *= require jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css
 *= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
 *= require msn-form.css
```

Comment: please show your application_day.css.

Comment: @SaurabhJain Please check now I have updated my question.

Comment: you mentioned that in order to get the data tables work you require `dataTables/src/demo_table_jui` in your css. However, the git url that you are using for your gem- https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails, doesn't have such requirement mentioned in the installation ?

Comment: I followed this cast and implemented it http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables  Which says I need to require them.

Comment: For those reading this in the future - if it's failing with rspec, simply add: gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git' and gem 'jquery-ui-rails' to the test environments in your gemfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your link - http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables, some changes to consider -

```
1)  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
```

**Note**- In the above, there is `github` and not `git`. Do exactly like that.

```
2) *= require jquery.ui.core
   *= require jquery.ui.theme
   *= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
```

**Note**- In your question there is no `core` and `theme` in custom css. Place them in the same order as they appear.

Also, dealing with data tables make sure you have following in `application.js` again in order-

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

Comment: I need to pass the full git path as I don't have bundler 1.1, mine is 1.0

Comment: Following above not working, then replace                            `require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui` with `require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui.css` and check if it works.

Comment: And as far as *= require jquery.ui.core
   *= require jquery.ui.theme is concerned I have my own CSS of Jquery UI which is different not the default one  which is called here *= require jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css

Comment: And as far as error is concerned just try the `General Installation` from github url - https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails, if it work.

Comment: If still got error then download the css `demo_table_jui` from http://code.google.com/p/virtual-judge/source/browse/trunk/judge/WebRoot/css/demo_table_jui.css?r=5.

Comment: Simply using gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails' doesn't work it says it can't find the file. Please check here i asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230182/datatables-with-rails-issue   Also please note that its working locally But its not working on dev and prod server.

Comment: rails version does matter. Check this https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/pull/4/files and follow its `Readme.md`

Comment: Thanks I solved it by downloading demo_table_jui.css from data-tables website and saved it in my stylesheet folder and renamed the path from  *= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui to *= require demo_table_jui.css